# Can I put <input> tag in insertRow() function? Not only text

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to use insertRow() function for adding rows in my table. but can I insert a row which contain `<input>` tag. because my table look like this

```
<table><thead>
  <tr>
    <th>No Account</th> 
    <th>Deskripsi</th>
    <th>Debit</th>
    <th>Credit</th>
    <th>Job</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="input-td" type="text" placeholder="No Account">  
    </td>
    <td><input class="input-td" type="text" placeholder="-"></td>
    <td><input class="input-td" type="text" placeholder="-"></td>
    <td><input class="input-td" type="text" placeholder="0"></td>
    <td><input class="input-td" type="text" placeholder="0"></td>
  </tr></thead>
</table>
```

`<a href="#" onclick="myCreateFunction()" name="add_row" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp Add row</a>`

so far i could only find this example for the javascript code

```
function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("bootstrap-data-table");
    var row = table.insertRow(3);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML = "0";
    cell2.innerHTML = "0";
    cell3.innerHTML = "0";
    cell4.innerHTML = "0";
    cell.innerHTML = "0";
}
```

could I change "0" which is only text to being input tag like the previous row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just assign an HTML string:

```
cell1.innerHTML = `<input class="input-td" type="text" placeholder="No Account">`;
```

Other options include creating the DOM via `document.createElement` and the like.

```
const input1 = document.createElement("input");
input1.classList.add("input-td");
input1.type = "text";
input1.placeholder = "No Account";
cell1.appendChild(input1);
```